# php date format

Tags: php

I have a date in a variable like: 01-01-2009 and need to change the format to Y-m-d. What should I use to do this conversion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert US date format to ANSI SQL date format (YYYY-mm-dd)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354838/convert-us-date-format-to-ansi-sql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the [`strtotime`](http://php.net/strtotime) and [`date`](http://php.net/date) functions like this:

```
$str = '01-01-2009';
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($str));

echo $date; //2009-01-01
```

Answer (score 0):

**To convert the date format from dd-mm-yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd** in php,

```
<?php

$dt='01-01-2009';
$dt=date('Y-m-d',strtotime($dt));
echo $dt;

?>
```

The o/p will be, `2009-01-01`