# how to convert date and time to another data time format

Tags: php

I want to convert my date into another format in PHP. I actually do'nt know the syntax. this is my date.

```
$date = "24-Feb-2013 11:35 AM"
```

and this is my format "March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm";

Comment: [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) is all you need. ;)

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613482/php-date-format

Comment: this question has the least effort possible put in. -1, google it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php
$date = "24-Feb-2013 11:35 AM";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
?>
```

Comment: Because you'll get a `DATETIME`, not a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @zessx Since when they are different in format? Links?

Comment: @CORRUPT http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/126208/datetime-vs-timestamp-in-mysql-and-php-in-practice

Comment: @CORRUPT `DATETIME` is timezone dependent, not `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: 1) uses date, which depends on server's timezone. 2) uses strtotime and there are better solutions, such as DateTime::createFromFormat where you can actually specify the format AND the time zone and format the output according to needs. But yes, it's no wonder that a reputation hunter will post horrible answer. Naturally, people will stumble upon it and use it thinking it's the correct solution when it really isn't. And 3) it doesn't output the timestamp. But of course, who cares about that, right?

Comment: @N.B. Don't you think that the question with such amount of effort does not deserve better answer?

Comment: @PLB - it's not about the question, people who google similar problems end up on SO and they read answers such as this one. Regardless whether question is horrible or not, if you answer - shouldn't it be an actual answer and not reputation hunting?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$date = "24-Feb-2013 11:35 AM";
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
```

read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: @Delta `$date = "24-Feb-2013 11:35 AM"` typo here. semi-colon: `;` is missing. :D btw, start learning php. :)