# Find days in a certain date

Tags: php, date

Hi I'm trying to echo just the days in a "31-10-15" but it isn't working.

```
$inpdate = "31-10-2015";
echo "inpdate " . $inpdate . "<br>";

$inpdate1 = strtotime($inpdate);
$inpdate1 = date('d-m-y',$inpdate1);
echo "inpdate1 " . $inpdate1 . "<br>";

$days = date('d', $inpdate1);
echo "days " . $days . "<br>";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613482/php-date-format)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$inpdate1` is not a valid string format for `date`, so change this line:

```
$days = date('d', $inpdate1);
```

to:

```
$days = date('d', strtotime($inpdate1));
```

Answer (score 2):

When you reassign $inpdate1 here

```
$inpdate1 = date('d-m-y',$inpdate1);
```

you're creating an invalid format that `date` can't read. Instead, echo it out without reassigning it.

```
$inpdate1 = strtotime($inpdate);
echo "inpdate1 " . date('d-m-y',$inpdate1) . "<br>";

$days = date('d', $inpdate1); // $inpdate1 is still in strtotime format
```