# There is any way to convert *this* date format to Y-m-d H:i:s?

Tags: php, date

As in title, I need to convert (for example) "Thu, 08 Oct 2020 08:32:44 GMT" format to Y-m-d H:i:s in php.

Anyone know how to do that ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3613482/php-date-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `strtotime` and `date` function <kbd>[See Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a5e24ab646dc11661621c8e357c05742cb10bcf)</kbd>

```
$ php -r '$str="Thu, 08 Oct 2020 08:32:44 GMT"; print date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$str"));'
2020-10-08 08:32:44
```

Better readable version

```
<?php

$str="Thu, 08 Oct 2020 08:32:44 GMT"; 
print date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("$str"));

?>
```

Comment: You're welcome, above output in php fiddle is from timezone US/Pacific, I hope your timezone set [with timezone](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7cc39ae53c18890d4f46329b36042b110942f0c6)

Comment: Akshay Hegde, maybe You know how to convert date format (like You wrote) but in foreach loop ?

Comment: @PawełSmacki just pass value over iteration in place of `$str`

Answer (score 2):

Use `DateTime::createFromFormat`. It allows to specify the format of the input, and with `format` you can specify the desired output:

```
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s e', 'Thu, 08 Oct 2020 08:32:44 GMT');
echo $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  // 2020-10-08 08:32:44
```

The [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) provides all the formatting characters you can use.

Comment: A upvote for the solution that correctly handles the time zone.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `date` to convert that. Pass the format string and the date in Unix timestamp (you can convert it using `strtotime`).

Example:

```php
$date = "Thu, 08 Oct 2020 08:32:44 GMT";
$newDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date));
```