# php generate date/ time in the same format appears mysql datatime

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I would like to know if there is a function in php to generate data/time format like in mysql : 0000-00-00 00:00:00 . 
I know you can generate data/time in the sql query with CURDATE() but I would like to know if it's possible to generate it with php in the same format mysql datatime format .

Comment: The date() function takes a format string and a timestamp and will do what you want. http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert US date format to ANSI SQL date format (YYYY-mm-dd)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354838/convert-us-date-format-to-ansi-sql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure is! Give this a go `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment PHP only supports RFC 2822 and ISO 8601 conform dates as well as Unix epoch timestamp. Check more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/de/datetime.formats.php).

The reason for that is probably that they include timezone offset, and the "mysql form"  - its a localized compbound format - doesnt, which would often lead to a mess in when using with application servers.

But you can define your own formats as you like, all the components are available via the datetime functions. Just have a look [here](http://php.net/manual/de/book.datetime.php) and [here](http://php.net/manual/de/function.date.php)

Example:

```
$mysql_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $unix_timestamp);
```

But be aware of the [Y2k38 bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem) if you are not on a 64 bit system, you may want to use the [datetime](http://www.php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) class

Answer (score 0):

This should convert the standard formats:

```
$format = 'DATETIME';

$format = str_replace(
    array('DATETIME', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'YEAR'),
    array('DATE TIME', 'Y-m-d', 'H:i:s', 'Y'),
$format);

echo date($format, time());
```