# Convert to date format from integer

Tags: mysql, sql, date

I have date in integer format 140529(yymmdd).  I want this date to be date format to be as 2014-05-29.

How can i do this . Please Help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert US date format to ANSI SQL date format (YYYY-mm-dd)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354838/convert-us-date-format-to-ansi-sql-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Alter column type to DATE!

Comment: It is strange to see you are talking of dates, but want to convert an integer (140529) to a string ('2014-05-29'). This is a mere string manipulation. But then, isn't there a database involved? In that case you would either you want to read from a column or write to a column, and that column would have to be of a DATE datatype to make sense. Hence your request seems a bit strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONCAT('20', SUBSTR ( 150817 , 0, 2 ), '-', SUBSTR ( 150817 , 3, 2 ), '-', SUBSTR ( 150817 , 5, 2 )) AS DATE;
```

And replace the "integer date" 150817 with your date

Comment: And this is for which dbms? Product specific SQL there, and question has no dbms tagged...